Is there a good way to validate each model attribute separately?
I'm working on an application that requires me to fill a model through several pages.
Hence, I need to validate each portion of attributes presented in each form.
I've found a way to do so, but I'm wondering if this seems correct, and if I could improve my code ?
def general
  @user = User.new
end

def save_general
  session[:user] ||= {}
  @user = User.new(params[:user].permit(:first_name))
  
  #Apparently, I need to run this once, to populate the errors array.
  @user.valid?

  unless @user.errors[:first_name].empty?
    render :general, status: :unprocessable_entity
  else
    session[:user][:first_name] = params[:user][:first_name]
  end
end


There are some things I would pick on if I were doing a code review (Use validate, not valid? if you're not checking the return value. Avoid double negation in unless ... .empty?, use if ... .present? instead). Could use some sanity checks in case a page is repeated, but overall seems great!

Multi-step forms are commonly called wizards - the Wicked gem is a classic for building them. You also want to look into the form object pattern instead of inlining all your validation logic in the controller. Controllers are notoriously hard to test.

You can easily move parts of the buisness logic out of the model into separate classes:
class UserNameForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attribute :first_name, :string
  validates :first_name, presence: true

  # This will make it behave like a User in forms.
  def model_name
    User.model_name
  end
end

This is commonly referred to as the form object pattern.
def save_general
  @form = UserNameForm.new(params[:user].permit(:first_name))
  # NEVER unless and else together
  if @form.valid?
    session[:user] ||= {}
    session[:user].merge(form.attributes)
  else
    render :general, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

It's kind of questionable if you want to tuck the attributes away into the session like this. On a successful form submission you could just render the next step of the form and include the stuff that's already been filled in as hidden inputs.

Thanks, @max! I'll try it that way. I didn't thought about hidden inputs, but won't it be redundant to revalidate the fields that were previously checked?

@trya2l the idea is that you create one form object for each form/step and set of validations.

Ok, I think that I get it, but when validating step2, will I also need to validate step1 form object if I use hidden inputs instead of wizard ?

Depends on how you implement it. But even if that's the case validations except for uniqueness have almost no computational cost.

Well, in the meanwhile I've taken a look at the wicked gem doc, and I've seen a way to resolve my problem. Thanks again!
